# How to draw and fill a pixel-perfect, symmetric ellipse in WinForms, GDI+?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I need to draw (and fill) a pixel-perfect, non anti-alised, symmetric ellipse.

I've tried various combinations of `InterpolationMode`, `SmoothingMode` and `PixelOffsetMode`, but none of the combinations I have tried made sure that the ellipse stays symmetric and non anti-alised at all sizes.

Unfortunately MSDN documentation on the subject is not very accurate.

[image: Ellipses not symmetric at all sizes]

Code used for drawing:

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.None;                                
g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(colorPalette.SelectedColor), rect);
```

The same goes for filling non anti-alised ellipses.

Does anyone know solution for this?

Comment: GDI+ is not well known for accuracy.  It interpolates using floating point internally and that has a knack for round-off error.  Use bitmaps if this really matters.

Comment: I need to draw ellipses of arbitrary size for a pixel-editing tool. Precision is of utmost importance. I'm afraid I'll have to implement Bresenham ellipse algorithm or something like that.

Comment: @JBeurer that's not an unreasonable solution

Answer (score 2):

try this, is it perfect enough? :)

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Bilinear;
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, rect);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't produce pixel perfect ellipses either. Ellipse with size (16,16) is not symmetric on X axis. :(

Comment: Indeed... Thus, using predefined or precalculated bitmaps would be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not up to a perfect circle for retina display, based on Leff's answer, changing the smoothing mode to antialias or high quality will fix the pixelate circle.

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```